# Add timestamp to copied folders and subfolders' names

Tags: batch-file

I want to transfer all sub-folders within Folder A to Folder B, and I am using this line:

```
xcopy C:\FolderA C:\FolderB /y /c
```

Now, how to add a time stamp to the names of all the sub-folders copied in folder B?

I am using a batch file in Windows Command Prompt.
Please help! 
Thank you.

Comment: What MS-DOS version?

Comment: I am sorry, I meant Command Prompt in Windows. I am using Windows 10. @LotPings

Comment: A timestamp appended to each **sub**folder but not the folder? Timestamp with what format?

Comment: Yes for example I have 5 folders in Folder A and now they are copied in Folder B, so all those 5 folder names should have a date and time stamp. It can be in any format. And no, I dont want a time stamp on Folder B's name.

Comment: Welcome as a new user to SO. Please take the [tour] and also read [ASK].
A [good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) shows your own coding effort. If **you** don't know what you want how could we? Only date or date time, date in yyyy-MM-dd or MM-dd-yyyy ....

Comment: yyyyMMdd-hhmmss I believe this should be fine with me. And thank you, I will definitely take this tour. :)

Comment: You said, add to the names. Where in relation to those existing directory names do you want the date and time stamp, `directorynamestamp`, `stampdirectoryname`, `directorystampname` or something else? Also, is there supposed to be any delimiter in between?

Comment: It will be directorynamestamp. And no, there won't be any delimiters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try.  I added some simple comments to explain what each line is doing.

```
@echo off
REM Get the date and time in the format: YYYYMMDDhhmmss
for /f "tokens=2 delims==." %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"

REM change the working directory to FolderA
cd /d "C:\FolderA"

REM Find all directories in FolderA
FOR /D %%G IN (*) DO (
    REM make a directory name with date and time stamp
    md "C:\FolderB\%%G%dt:~0,8%-%dt:~8,6%"
    xcopy "%%G\*" "C:\FolderB\%%G%dt:~0,8%-%dt:~8,6%\" /E
)
pause
```

Comment: Open up a cmd prompt and learn to use the help system for the commands you are using in the script. You can type the command name followed by a forward slash and question mark to get help for any command. `for /?`  `md /?`  and so on.

Comment: Thank you so so much. It is working perfectly fine. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue myself, so its done. Thank you again!